# Raw HTML in Form Filter

Tags: symfony1, admin-generator

At my company, we had developed a athletes management solution, were each athlete is inserted in the application by administrators users. For the referred solution, it was used the symfony admin generator.

On the second project iteration, one of the clients request was to turn the printed athletes list more legible. To accomplish that, we had created proper CSS styles, to be used when the user selects the browser print option.

However, the athletes form filter has some HTML tags (symfony widgets) whose do not render properly, namely, the select tag that has possible multiple choices (the select choices do not appear on the print preview).

So, I would to know if is possible to insert raw HTML directly on the form filter (get the selected options and convert them is labels or plain text), that will be only visible when the user selects the print option.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a custom widget in place of the standard choice widget that adds in the values you want to be shown when printing but hidden with styles by default. Then you show them using your print style sheet.